# Keyboard stops working

Tags: modeling

Recently after upgrading to Blender 2.82 on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS I've run into an issue where blender just stops responding to my keyboard. This includes shortcuts and text entry. Any ideas?

Comment: Resetting the preferences removed the problem for me but I have no idea what causes it in the first place.

Comment: Were you maybe clicked onto another tab, and the keyboard input went there instead? I know that's happened to me a TON, and I've had a lot of backspacing to do when I brought blender up over Java, while trying to animate or model something new I've thought of during the course of coding.